# how to prevent renamed Xcode project from replacing icon on iPhone springboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Xcode 7.3

My app is installed on my demo iPhone4.
I want to quickly create a modified version of my app on the iPhone4, but want to keep the original app also.
I changed project name.
However, when I run it, it replaced the original icon, shown in springboard, with same icon, as expected, and with new project name.

How can I have both the original app and the new app?

Comment: The bundle identifier needs to be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the bundle identifier so that the new app does not replace the original app.